# Splitting of short exact sequence of strongly-semistable sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, short-exact-sequences

Does short exact sequence of strongly semi-stable bundles (torsion-free sheaves) of the same slope split after applying few Frobenius pullbacks? Strongly semi-stable means that pullback under Frobenius is also semi-stable. This is well-known to be true for curves. Because there is a finite etale map that the pullback along that turns the exact sequence to a sequence of vector bundles of the form $\bigoplus \mathcal{O}(n)$ for a fixed $n$, which splits.